# Improving the runtime of Insertion sort

Tags: java, runtime

Just to practice and improve my programming skills I decided to solve the questions on InterviewStreet. I decided to start off using simple InsertionSort (I expected it to be simple).
https://www.interviewstreet.com/challenges/dashboard/#problem/4e90477dbd22b
I am able to get correct answers. However the runtime is a problem. The max allowed runtime for the test cases is 5s. However I am going slightly overboard.
I used a few tricks (like removing something out of code. Storing the result of str.lenght() etc). However I am still slightly overboard.

The current runtimes for the ten test cases are:

1   Passed  Success             0.160537

2   Passed  Success             0.182606

3   Passed  Success             0.172744

4   Passed  Success             0.186676

5   Failed  Time limit exceeded.    5.19279

6   Failed  Time limit exceeded.    5.16129

7   Passed  Success             2.91226

8   Failed  Time limit exceeded.    5.14609

9   Failed  Time limit exceeded.    5.14648

10  Failed  Time limit exceeded.    5.16734

I am not aware what the test cases are.
Kindly help me improve the runtime.
Thank you.

```
import java.util.Scanner;
import java.io.*;
//import java.io.BufferedWriter;
//import java.io.FileInputStream;
//import java.io.FileOutputStream;

public class Solution {
    public static int[] A=new int[100001]; 
    public static int swap=0;
    public static void InsertionSort(int n){
    for (int i=1; i<=n; i++){    
        for (int var=i; var>0; var--){
            if (A[var]<A[var-1]){
                int temp=A[var-1];
                A[var-1]=A[var];
                A[var]=temp;
                swap++;
            }
            else {
                break;
            }
        }
    }
    }


    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException  {
        BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(System.in));

        String str = br.readLine();
        int number_of_cases =Integer.parseInt(str);
        int counter;
        int [] spacearray = new int[100000];

        for (int j=0; j<number_of_cases; j++){
            swap=0;
            str = br.readLine();
            int arraylength = Integer.parseInt(str);

            str = br.readLine();
            counter=0;
            int strlen=str.length();
            for (int i=0; i<strlen-1; i++){
                if (str.charAt(i) == ' '){
                    spacearray[counter]=i;
                    counter++;
                }
            }
            spacearray[counter]=strlen;

            A[0]=Integer.parseInt(str.substring(0, spacearray[0]));
            for (int i=1; i<=arraylength-1; i++){
                A[i] = Integer.parseInt(str.substring(spacearray[i-1]+1,spacearray[i]));
            }

            InsertionSort(arraylength-1);

            System.out.println(swap);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Considering the facts that insertion sort is `O(n^2)` and `N` may reach 100000, there's a chance that an algorithm better than simulation is needed.

Comment: It also may be better to read in the `A[i]`s with `StringTokenizer`s.

Comment: I guess you are wasting too much time parsing your stuff. Consider using a precompiled pattern instead of substring'ing.

Comment: oh! yes!
so instead of actually swapping..I can actually count the number of elements greater that are to the right of this element!

Comment: It's a bit more complicated than just counting the number of greater elements. If you check the hint, there's a `O(log n)` algorithm, I think.

Answer (score 0):

Use binary indexed trees to solve this problem

Answer (score 0):

The bottleneck here is the insertion sort algorithm. It's time complexity is O(n^2) and with n up to 10^5, one can easily exceed 5 seconds on the interviewstreet judge machine. Also when a TLE signal is thrown, your program stops executing. So the slight overhead to 5 isn't really an indicator of the actual time it takes to run. It is introduced by the delay between detecting TLE and stopping the execution.

For the sake of history, this question appeared originally as a part of codesprint-1. Using insertion sort isn't the way to proceed here, otherwise the question would have been a complete give away.

**Hint**

Use the fact that all values will be within [1,10^6]. What you are really doing here is finding the number of inversions in the array A, i.e. find all pairs of i < j s.t. A[i] > A[j]. Think of a data structure that allows you to find the number of swaps needed for each insert operation in logarithmic time complexity (like [Binary Indexed Trees](http://community.topcoder.com/tc?module=Static&d1=tutorials&d2=binaryIndexedTrees)). Of course, there are other approaches.